# Reassigning a list to [] while iterating it does not stop the loop

Tags: python

Why does the below for loop still executes fully, despite reassigning the list to []?

```
def iterate(l):
    for x in l:
        l = []
        print(x)
        
iterate([1, 2, 3]) # prints 1 2 3
```

I know it is rather a bad practice, but I am interested in the "science" behind this behavior.
Inspecting the `l` variable in the debugger, I can see it becomes `[]`; I cannot see the original one though.

Comment: `l = []` is an assignment, not a declaration.  In any case, it doesn't affect the loop because you aren't changing the original list.  You're changing the variable that the list came from.  It's very differfent.

Comment: The loop loops over the elements in whatever the *local name* `l` points to, then you change what the *local name* `l` points to to `[]` inside the loop, but that will not change the loop over the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your `for` loop.

```
for x in l:
    l = []
    print(x)
```

It's basically equivalent to this.

```
it = iter(l)
try:
    while True:
        x = next(it)
        l = []
        print(x)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

By the time we hit the `l = []` line, we *don't need* the variable `l` anymore. The thing we're actually using is `it`, an iterator pointing to the list we're iterating over. Whether or not the actual variable `l` still points to that list is irrelevant, as we've got our own variable (our iterator) pointing to it separately. So your reassignment doesn't affect the loop.

Comment: Thanks! And in order to see the **real** source code to your equivalent, I would need to dive into the C implementation of Python's for loop I guess?

Comment: @barciewicz Correct. Assuming you're using CPython, then `for` loops compile down to a special opcode called `FOR_ITER`, which is handled at the C level.